# Ubuntu12.04 crashed while trying to install Ubuntu14.04, no longer have access

Tags: crash, ubuntu-12.04

My desktop crashed. It's a 9 year old Compaq SR 1650NX, AMD Athlon 3500+  probably 1 GB RAM.

Was running Ubuntu 12.04... was attempting to upgrade to 14.04, not sure if I interrupted it.

Pretty much stuck on (constantly redirected to) a page which says "GNU Grub version 1.99-2". It offers several choices (as written):

- Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-67-generic
- Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-67-generic (recovery mode)
- Previous Linux versions
- Memory Test (memtest86+)
- Memory Test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)

But none of the selections seem to be able to get me anywhere (i.e., I click yes, but can't seem to run any commands - not that I know anything useful). I escape from those pages by repeatedly hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

Any help would be appreciated; will provide additional info when requested.

Comment: Are you saying if you attempt to boot into Ubuntu the computer will simply reboot and you will be provide the boot options again?

Answer (score 0):

On a different computer download the Ubuntu installer CD-ROM disc image and burn it to a CD.  Reinstall on the dead computer using that disc.  You will then start with a new system.  Be aware that any information you have on the current system will be erased by doing so.  If you need to salvage any information then you will need data recovery tools.  You can try to fix your corrupted installation all you want without any guarantee of success or you can just install fresh and everything will just work.  The Ubuntu installer is pretty straight-forward and should present minimal difficulty during the process.